# javascript form cannot display

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs

I have a JS which looks like below whereby I'm trying to build a form with several tabs, and under each tab I would like to add some labels, fields, radiogroups and the likes.
I'm still at the beginning but already encountering problems; the tabs show fine on all occasions but after the 'Contact No.' label, I can't see items falling directly below it but
can see address tabs. Can anyone show me where m getting this wrong!! 
I want the 'Contact No.' label to act as a heading to mobile, home, pager and email text fields.

```
this.buildForm = function(){
        this.myForm = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
            layout:'column',
            border: false,
            labelWidth: labelWidth,
            anchor: "100%",
            items:[{
                columnWidth: 1,
                xtype:'tabpanel',
                activeTab: 0,
                height:420,
                enableTabScroll: true,
                deferredRender: false,
                bodyStyle:'padding:10px',
                items: [
                    {
                        title: 'Contact No. & Address',
                        i18nTitle: 'Person.contactNoAndAddress.title',
                        border: false,
                        items: [
                            {
                                xtype:'label',
                                text: 'Contact No.',
                                i18nTitle: 'Person.contactNo.title',
                                id: 'contactNo',
                                layout: 'column',
                                items: [
                                    {

                                        columnWidth: 0.33,
                                        layout: 'form',
                                        items:[
                                            {
                                                xtype:'textfield',
                                                fieldLabel: 'Mobile',
                                                tabIndex:101, 
                                                colwidth: 40
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    },{
                                        columnWidth: 0.33,
                                        layout: 'form',
                                        items:[
                                            {
                                                xtype:'textfield',
                                                fieldLabel: 'Home',
                                                tabIndex:102, 
                                                colwidth: 40
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    },{
                                        columnWidth: 0.33,
                                        layout: 'form',
                                        items:[
                                            {
                                                xtype:'textfield',
                                                fieldLabel: 'Office',
                                                tabIndex:103, 
                                                colwidth: 40
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    },{
                                        columnWidth: 0.33,
                                        layout: 'form',
                                        items:[
                                            {
                                                xtype:'textfield',
                                                fieldLabel: 'Pager',
                                                tabIndex:104, 
                                                colwidth: 40
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    },{
                                        columnWidth: 0.33,
                                        layout: 'form',
                                        items:[
                                            {
                                                xtype:'textfield',
                                                fieldLabel: 'Fax',
                                                tabIndex:105, 
                                                colwidth: 40
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    },{
                                        columnWidth: 1,
                                        layout: 'form',
                                        items:[
                                            {
                                                xtype:'textfield',
                                                fieldLabel: 'Email',
                                                width:200,
                                                tabIndex:106, 
                                                width: 200
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            },{
                                xtype:'tabpanel',
                                id: 'addressTab',
                                permission:'person:responsibleAdmin',
                                activeTab: 0,
                                height:220,
                                enableTabScroll: false,
                                deferredRender: false,
                                bodyStyle:'padding:10px',
                                layoutOnTabChange: true,
                                items: [
                                    {
                                        title: 'Home Address',
                                        i18nTitle: 'Person.homeAddress.title',
                                        border: false,
                                        // hideMode: "offsets",
                                        items:[{}]
                                    },{
                                        title: 'Work Address',
                                        i18nTitle: 'Patient.workAddress.title',
                                        border: false,
                                        // hideMode: "offsets",
                                        items:[{}]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    },{
                        title:'Next of Kin',
                        i18nTitle: 'Person.nextOfKin.title',
                        layout: 'column',
                        labelWidth: 100,
                        items:[{

                        }]
                    }
                ]
            }]
        });
        return this.myForm;
    }
```

Comment: can you post a jsfiddle for this?

Comment: @MaurizioIndenmark i haven't used fiddle before but i am now, so far without luck. (fiddle gives no output)

Comment: if you can post it here people can help you better as they can test your code

Comment: i found an example on the net on fiddle and added my code to it, this is how it looks [link](http://jsfiddle.net/zWdXf/1/) . from the code, I only changed on the **items**

Comment: can you simplify the fiddle getting rid of what is not really needed and try to isolate the problem.

Comment: I cleaned it, fiddle can be found here [link](http://jsfiddle.net/zWdXf/4/)

Comment: or this link [my code on fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zWdXf/5/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand properly, for what you want to obtain you need the text field `Mobile` to be at the same level as the label `Contact No` and not to be his child.

have a look at how I modified the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zWdXf/6/

Here is the detail of that part of code that you need:

```
            items: [{
                xtype: 'label',
                text: 'Contact No.2',
                i18nTitle: 'Person.contactNo.title',
                id: 'contactNo',
                layout: 'column',
                items: [{}]
            },{
                xtype: 'textfield',
                fieldLabel: 'Mobile',
                i18nTitle: 'Person.contactNo.title',
                id: 'contactNo2',
                layout: 'column',
                items: [{}]
            }, {
                xtype: 'tabpanel',
                id: 'addressTab',
                permission: 'person:responsibleAdmin',
                activeTab: 0, [...]
```

Comment: your example could work but I want lable Contact No. to be the parent of several text fields, Mobile, Home, Page, Fax... of which will be arranged 3 text fields per row.

Comment: You can't have a text field as a child of a label. A label is not a container element. Can't Contact No. become another type of object?

Comment: Ah okay I see, you are right, so I changed label to title and got what I am looking for. But then I don't understand why [this](http://jsfiddle.net/lee_rooy/zWdXf/8/) wouldn't work. That is after putting field label 'Home' inside items: tag

Comment: try to remove the part you think is causing the problem and see if it works. so you isolate the problem and you can then find a solution